# How can I see which processes upload/download how much data? [Debian 9]

Tags: debian, networking, monitoring, traffic, gnome-system-monitor

So I'd like to gain some insight into which processes (incl. daemons) upload and download how much data on my Debian 9 machine.

Sadly the System Monitor does not display such information. I'd prefer a GUI over the console. I have tried `nethogs` which is probably what people would recommend for such endeavors, however it only shows the *current* network traffic processes instead of cumulative information such as a proper statistic or ordered list. I'm aware of wireshark.

Comment: There is no cumulative data unless you store it explicitly. You may use iptables counters (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548383/how-can-i-check-the-hit-count-for-each-rule-in-iptables) or send each daemon traffic via proxy and parse its logs (like squid http proxy logs may be processed with SquidAnalyzer or awstats etc)

Answer (score 1):

If the optional [netatop](https://www.atoptool.nl/netatop.php) kernel module is loaded and `netatopd` is running, `atop` can show this information.